# SQLSTATE[42000]のSQL構文エラーが発生する

Tags: php, linux, mysql, mariadb

**前提・実現したいこと**

PHPで店舗検索の機能が以前実装されており、今回バージョンが上がったローカル環境下で動くか確認したところ、
下記のエラーが発生しております。
エラーがどこで起きているのか、教えていただきたいです。

**発生しているエラーメッセージ**

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near ''0', '20'' at line 1
```

**該当のソースコード**

```
    /**
     * お店情報を取得
     *
     * @param  Nagi_DB $db     データベースオブジェクト
     * @param  integer $start  開始
     * @param  integer $length 取得数
     * @param  array   $cond   取得条件
     * @return array お店情報を格納した配列
     * @throws データベースとのやり取りに失敗
     */
    public static function get($db, $start, $length, $cond = array())
    {
        try {
            $params = array();
            $table = ABAHOUSE_Shop_DB::getTableName(self::$_language, 'shop');
            $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `' . $table . '` ';
            if ($cond) {
                $sql .= 'WHERE ';
                $where = '';
                foreach ($cond as $k => $t) {
                    if ($where) {
                        $where .= 'AND ';
                    }
                    if ($k === 'area') {
                        if (!is_array($t)) {
                            $where .= '`area_id` = ? ';
                            $params[] = ABAHOUSE_Shop_Area::getId($db, $t);
                        } else
                        {
                            $tmp = '';
                            foreach ((array)$t as $v) {
                                $tmp .= '?,';
                                $params[] = $v;
                            }
                            $where .= '`area_id` IN (' . trim($tmp, ',') . ') ';
                        }
                    }
                    if ($k === 'genre') {
                        $where .= 'FIND_IN_SET(?, `kind`) ';
                        $params[] = $t;
                    }
                    if ($k === 'shop') {
                        $where .= '(FIND_IN_SET(?, `category`) OR FIND_IN_SET(?, `shop_brand`)) ';
                        $params[] = $t;
                        $params[] = $t;
                    }
                    if ($k === 'brand') {
                        $where .= '(`category` LIKE ? OR `brand` LIKE ?) ';
                        $params[] = '%' . $t . '%';
                        $params[] = '%' . $t . '%';
                    }
                }
                $sql .= $where;
            }
            $params[] = $start;
            $params[] = $length;

            $sql .= 'ORDER BY `area_id` LIMIT ?, ?';

            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute($params);
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $result = array();
            if ($rows) {
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    $shop = new ABAHOUSE_Shop();
                    $shop->name      = $row['name'];
                    $shop->address   = $row['address'];
                    $shop->map       = $row['map'];
                    $shop->tel       = $row['tel'];
                    //$shop->blog      = $row['blog'];
                    $shop->blog      = $row['blog'] ? explode(',', $row['blog']) : null;
                    $shop->site      = $row['site'];
                    $shop->hours     = $row['hours'];
                    $shop->shopBrand = explode(',', $row['shop_brand']);
                    $shop->kind      = explode(',', $row['kind']);
                    $shop->brand     = explode(',', $row['brand']);
                    $shop->category  = explode(',', $row['category']);
                    $result[] = $shop;
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

**試したこと**

以前の環境下では問題なく、動いていますので、環境が変わったことによるコードの修正が必要のようです。
また、DBをMariaDBからMySQLに変更しましたが、同様にエラーが発生しました。

**補足情報**

以前の環境

- apache 2.2
- PHP 5.1.6
- mysql 不明
- Linux (CentOS6.7)

現在のローカル環境

- apache 2.4.46
- PHP 7.4.11
- MariaDB 10.4.14
- Windows (XAMPP3.2.4)

※同様の質問を [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/299421) にてしております。そちらで解決しましたら、こちらでも共有いたします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/299421) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。編集させていただきました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
をtry文の先頭に配置したところ、動くようになりました。